# I want to set is_admin to True instead of is_user in my Flask application

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a flask application and in my models I have a User. I want to set is_admin to True when the user.id is 19 but it always set is_user to True.

This is what I have done:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    is_user = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    books = db.relationship('Book', backref="users")
    journals = db.relationship('Journal', backref="users")
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.now())

    def set_user(self):
        if self.id == 19:
            self.is_admin = True
        else:
            self.is_user = True

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.set_user()

    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, username=self.username, email=self.email)
```

This is what I had:

```json
{
    "message": "User created",
    "user": {
        "email": "test19@email.com",
        "id": 19,
        "is_admin": false,
        "is_user": true,
        "username": "test19"
    }
}
```

This is what I was expecting:

```json
{
    "message": "User created",
    "user": {
        "email": "test19@email.com",
        "id": 19,
        "is_admin":true,
        "is_user": false,
        "username": "test19"
    }
}
```

Comment: If `is_admin` and `is_user` are conditional on `id` do you really need to store them ?

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the objects?

Comment: print `self.id` in `set_user` to see what ID your user actually has.

Comment: I am creating an API and  I want to use the is_admin feature to build the admin panel

Comment: @ Sebastian and @Aymen: ok

Answer (score 0):

Since `is_admin` and `is_user` are fully dependent on `id` and trivial to calculate, I'd argue you do not need to store them in the database.

You can use a python [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to set them as property attributes on your `User` class.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.id == 19

    @property
    def is_user(self):
        return self.id != 19

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", future=True, echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(bind=engine)

admin = User(id=19)
ljmc = User(id=1337)

session.add(admin)  
session.add(ljmc)
session.commit()  # INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES ((19,), (1337,));

admin.is_admin  # `SELECT user.id AS user_id FROM user WHERE user.id = 19` gives True
ljmc.is_admin  # `SELECT user.id AS user_id FROM user WHERE user.id = 1337` gives False
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Moreover, I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy instead of  SQLAlchemy

Comment: I saw you're using the `db.Model` of Flask-SQLAlchemy, but things are mostly transparent, hope that's ok, let me know if you need help transcribing to Flask-SQLAlchemy.